# onclick function in IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I've this template for function call to show some detail.
It is working in IE9 but not in IE11. How to make it compatible for IE11?
The event is not getting called.

```
 <xsl:template name="DrillLink">
            <xsl:param name="ObjectName" select="''"/>
            <xsl:param name="ObjectID" select="''"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(@ObjectType = 'BO' or @ObjectType = 'SO') and @DetailEnabled = '1' and @HideDetail = '0' ">
                    <span href="javascript:;"  onMouseOver="window.status='Drill down {@ObjectName}'; return true;" value ="'0'" onMouseOut="window.status=''; return true;"
                        onClick="showDetail(this); return false;" box_name="expand" id="ShowDetail" style="margin-right:5;" detailIndent="1"
                        title="{@ObjectDetailText}"
                        OrderKey="{@OrderKey}"
                        StartDate="{@Date}" EndDate="{@Date}"
                        ObjectID = "{@ChildObjList}"
                        Duration    = "{@Date}"
                        TimeZoneID = "{@TimeZoneID}"
                        TransformUpID = "{@TransformUp}"
                        TransformDownID = "{@TransformDown}"
                        RoundTypeID = "{@RoundType}"
                        PrecisionID = "{@Precision}"
                        CarryForwardPrecisionID = "{@CarryForwardPrecision}"
                        UserID = "{@UserID}"
                        EnableObjectType = "{@ObjectType}"
                        DisplayBuilderID = "{@DisplayBuilderID}"
                        RealTimeView = "{@RealTimeView}"
                        ForwardHour = "{@ForwardHour}"
                        BackwardHour = "{@BackwardHour}"
                        class = "dmActionBtn"
                    >+</span>
                    <xsl:text>&amp;#160;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(@ObjectID) = 0 ">
                            <xsl:text>&amp;#160;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>

                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: `onClick` should be lowercase. Just like your `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`. Some browsers tolerate the (incorrect) capitalisation, and some do not.

Comment: I think you need to show more context, do you use XSLT in the browser or server-side? If server-side, do you serve the result as `text/html`? And we need to see any `xsl:output` in the XSLT, plus any namespaces you might put on result elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- `onClick` should be lowercase, as **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)**
- `onMouseOver` should be lowercase, as **[`onmoueover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover)**
- `onMouseOut` should be lowercase, as **[`onmouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseout)**

Some browsers tolerate the (incorrect) capitalisation, and some do not (which would explain the inconsistencies between them).

Also, note that you should **not** be using inline event handlers to begin with, and should instead be making use of **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to attach the respective events to the elements:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well, at least in HTML 4 and 5 served as text/html the case of attribute names does not matter and any mix is explicitly allowed, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes states clearly "In the HTML syntax, attribute names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters" and https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/about.html#h-1.2.1 also " Recall that in HTML, element and attribute names are case-insensitive". So unless the XSLT result is treated as X(HT)ML I don't think the case of the event handler attributes matters.